# How should fitness games be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm currently playing Zumba Fitness 2 on my Nintendo Wii and asked a [question regarding an accessory](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/how-do-i-prevent-the-zumba-fitness-2-belt-from-slipping-off) that came with the game. What tags should games like these have?

I've added the [zumba](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zumba), [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games), [belt](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt) to my question. The "zumba" tag makes sense, but I'm iffy on the other two. "Belt" might be too granular but "accessory" sounds too general. The "games" tag I'm using refers to video games. Should the game be tagged as [zumba-fitness-2](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zumba-fitness-2)?

Comment: I'd add zumba and zumba-fitness, given our volume I'm not sure we'd need to be so specific

Comment: I think the games tag is key - maybe more important for this question than the Zumba tag. There's a big difference (I assume) between Zumba the dance/fitness class and a video game. Maybe change games->video-games if confusing? I'd probably leave out the belt tag altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a game-specific tag using the full title of the game ([zumba-fitness-2](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zumba-fitness-2)), then [zumba](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zumba) for the exercise in general, and maybe [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) as well. There's potential for confusion with the latter if it ends up a mix of video games and outdoor games, but it's not necessarily a problem. For me (although I'm admittedly a layman here), a video fitness game is in the same ballpark as an outdoor game.

Tags are more about categorizing questions and supporting people following a tag to discover questions that are relevant to them. Will anyone ever follow [belt](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt)? Probably not. Does it carry any clear meaning by itself? Not really.

Whereas using the game title will help others "playing" it find relevant questions and the more general [zumba](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zumba) tag can attract other zumba enthusiasts.

Comment: I think I added the "belt" tag because I had seen other questions about weightlifting belts. Coincidentally, none of them have a "belt" tag.