# What's the difference between the [games] and [video-games] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Both the tags [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) and [video-games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) seem to be used solely for video games right now, and neither tag has a description.

There was some previous discussion in [How should fitness games be tagged?](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/how-should-fitness-games-be-tagged), but it didn't provide a clear answer on what the difference between the two tags is and when to use one versus the other.

I can see a few ways of handling this:

1. Merge the tags
2. Make them mutually exclusive - use [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) for games that are not video games
3. Consider [video-games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) a subset of  [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games)

What do people think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I naturally consider video games a specific subset of games, but there isn't anything to really denote a hierarchy of tags in the site.

For the current questions we have under [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games), the [video-games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) tag is more appropriate and accurate. I would retag those questions under [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) and not merge them at all in case any questions come up that are games but aren't video games. Tagging a questions under "games" itself is pretty broad, and I would prefer seeing tags that were a bit more narrow that really the describe the core of the question subject.

**Update:** I've gone ahead and retagged the questions under "games" as "video games" but without creating any tag synonyms or merges.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to retag questions tagged [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) with [video-games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) for the moment (or the other way round).

As you can see all the questions tagged [video-games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) are newer than the questions tagged [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games). In my opinion [video-games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) describes them better, but [games](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) should be available for non video games. (Although I cannot immediately see questions that might fit into our scope, but whatever)

Comment: For the questions that we have now, [tag:video-games] is more accurate than just [tag:games] so I'm more inclined to retag the current questions under games as video games. If there are questions that fit into [tag:games] that aren't video games, then that tag would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there is a very clear distinction between the two tags, though it is not immediately apparent from reading tagged questions. If you agree with this description, then we should probably write tag wikis to help explain the distinction.

**Games**

These are physical activities you play that are games but not sports. Examples include playing tag, capture the flag, and ultimate frisbee.

**Video-games**

These are any (motion-controlled) video games you play which result in you being physically active. Example games include Wii Sports, Zumba, and Dance Dance Revolution, while potential platforms include arcades, Nintendo Wii, and XBox with Kinect.